# Remove duplicates and take the latest data based on timestamp in a csv file using linux

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, csv, awk

I have a huge csv file (100,000 records), which has data like below:

```
Col1  Col2       Date & Time 
a     xyz      Oct 31 2014 09:01 
b     xyz      Dec 12 2013 08:15 
a     xyz      Oct 30 2014 07:01 
c     xyz      Dec 26 2013 08:39 
a     xyz      Nov 12 2014 08:25 
c     xyz      Dec 12 2013 08:10 
b     xyz      Dec 12 2013 09:21
```

I need to remove the duplicates and keep only that data which is latest (based on the third column - Date & time). So the output should be like

```
 Col1    Col2        Date & Time 
    a     xyz      Nov 12 2014 08:25 
    b     xyz      Dec 12 2013 09:21
    c     xyz      Dec 26 2013 08:39
```

I tried to sort the file first and and then remove the duplicates, but that's failing for this huge csv file. Can someone help?

P.S. In col1, data can be from a-z multiple times. Its just a sample here.

Comment: Not clear: is there any specific separator in between columns? a tab maybe? that is: what does indicate when a column finishes and starts next one?

Comment: @fedorqui - As I mentioned, Its a CSV (Comma separated) file. So, the columns would be separted by ',' only...

Comment: Then see the update in my answer.

Comment: Are you looking to dedupe column 1, column2, or column 1 and 2?

Comment: @Sobrique apparently just col1.

Answer (score 0):

Let's give a try with this:

```
while IFS="," read -r a b c
do
  printf "%s %s %s %d\n" "$a" "$b" "$c" $(date -d"$c" +"%s")
done < file | \
awk '{it=$NF; NF--
      if (max[$1]<it) {max[$1]=it; res[$1]=$0}}
        END {for (i in max) print res[i]}'
```

This stores the maximum date in the array `max[]`, which is indexed by the temporary last field which indicates seconds since 1 Jan 1970 (created previously with the `while read` bash). After processing the whole block, in `END{}`, it prints the result.

It returns:

```
a xyz Nov 12 2014 08:25
b xyz Dec 12 2013 09:21
c xyz Dec 26 2013 08:39
```

If it happens to be comma separated, use:

```
$ while IFS="," read -r a b c; do printf "%s,%s,%s,%d\n" "$a" "$b" "$c" $(date -d"$c" +"%s"); done < a | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {it=$NF; NF--
          if (max[$1]<it) {max[$1]=it; res[$1]=$0}}
            END {for (i in max) print res[i]}'
a,xyz,Nov 12 2014 08:25
b,xyz,Dec 12 2013 09:21
c,xyz,Dec 26 2013 08:39
```

Comment: This will be slow for a large file.

Comment: I have other than a,b and c also. this I just put random here. in column1, a to z data is there. so, i guess this would fail !

Comment: @user3884944 then do not make people loose time and post more representative data.

Comment: How I can put 100,000 records here?? I just gave a sample here, csv file can contain f two times, e 3 times and so on.... 
Pardon, if I was not clear enough !

Comment: @user3884944 no, definitely you weren't clear at all. Provide a more general approach on how your fields look like. Not in comments, but updating your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's 3 steps to your process. 
First:

- extract the key fields. (I'd use perl and split).
- Parse the date into a numeric format. You could either do some sort of ISO style e.g. 2014-12-26 08:39 or turn it into a Unix 'epoch' time. (If it's CSV, you could probably munge it through Excel if you really wanted.)
- run through your inputs, discarding any 'old' values.

So with that in mind - and assuming that because you've said 'CSV' you mean it's actually comma separated values.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my %most_recent;

my $header = <DATA>;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ( $col1, $col2, $date_and_time ) = split( /,\s*/, $line, 3 );
    $date_and_time =~ s/\s+$//g;

    my $time = Time::Piece ->  new -> strptime( $date_and_time, "%b %d %Y %H:%M" );

    if ( not defined $most_recent{$col1}{$col2}
        or $most_recent{$col1}{$col2} < $time )
    {
        $most_recent{$col1}{$col2} = $time;
    }
}

print "Most recent:\n";
foreach my $col1 ( keys %most_recent ) {
    foreach my $col2 ( keys %{ $most_recent{$col1} } ) {
        print "$col1, $col2, $most_recent{$col1}{$col2}, \n";
    }
}


__DATA__
Col1, Col2,       Date & Time 
a, xyz,      Oct 31 2014 09:01 
b, xyz,      Dec 12 2013 08:15 
a, xyz,      Oct 30 2014 07:01 
c, xyz,      Dec 26 2013 08:39 
a,     xyz,      Nov 12 2014 08:25 
c,     xyz,      Dec 12 2013 08:10 
b,     xyz,      Dec 12 2013 09:21
```

This will - for each unique pairing of `Col1` and `Col2` run through picking out the most recent timestamp for that pair.

Note - at various steps (split and timestamp parse) whitespace is discarded.